# Is there any function in reactor.util.retry.Retry that i can use when retry is successful

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I need to perform some action immediately after Retry is successful for server-sent event implementation, I was unable to find any method in **reactor.util.retry.Retry**.  Is there any other alternate to do **doOnRetrySuccess(func)**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a built-in operator to do this, but you could utilize an `AtomicBoolean` to detect if the onNext/onComplete signal occurs immediately after a retry:

```java
final AtomicBoolean retrying = new AtomicBoolean();

monoOrFlux
        .retryWhen(Retry
                // Configure whatever retry behavior you want here.
                // For simplicity, this example uses .indefinitely()
                .indefinitely()
                // Set the retrying flag to indicate that a retry is being attempted.
                .doBeforeRetry(signal -> retrying.set(true)))
        // Check and reset the retrying flag in doOnEach.
        // This example uses doOnEach, which works for both Mono and Flux.
        // If the stream is a Mono, then you could simplify this to use doOnSuccess instead.
        .doOnEach(signal -> {
            if ((signal.isOnNext() || signal.isOnComplete())
                    && retrying.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                // This is the first onNext signal emitted after a retry,
                // or the onComplete signal (if no element was emitted) after a retry.
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I am consuming server-sent events (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events) and doOnEach is not called as soon as retry is successful, It is only called when there is an event after successful retry.

Comment: you could use a similar approach with a `doOnSubscribe` BUT placed before `retryWhen`. You'd need the atomic(boolean|integer) to detect the first subscription (which is the original non-retry one) vs subsequent subscriptions (which are, likely, retries). you might need to wrap both the atomic and Flux in a `defer` to ensure atomic is not sharing state between multiple subscribers